# How to get JSON data from JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

I need to do an applet. This applet it is a stand reminder. I use a JSON file.
I need to do a dropdown menu so I did this code in my JSON file :

```
`"questions": [
      {
        "key": "reminder",
        "label": "Choose the time",
        "help": "You can find the stock ticker on the web",
        "required": true,
        "order": 1,
        "controlType": "dropdown",
        "options":[10, 15, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
      }
    ],`
```

The options is a list in order to allow the user to choose when he want an alert. But I need to take the options in like an entry in my JS file, in order after to count down the time after with a function.
Can you help me please to find how can I take `options` like an entry and to display it a JS file?

Comment: *"I need to do an applet."* I suspect you're not using the correct term there. Do you mean a web app? "Applet" usually refers to the obsolete Java technology.

Comment: Fetch the json file inside the js script, parse the json file, extract the options from the resulting object.

Comment: @Shilly yes It is what I want to do but I don'y know how can I code this

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I had to do something like that > https://github.com/daskeyboard/daskeyboard-applet--weather-forecast  but my subject it is a stand remider

Comment: @shirleytb hev1s answer below will get you halfway there. Put your json file on a web server so you can `fetch()` it. Point the url to this file. The `res.json()` bit will then parse your json file into a JS object if it's valid json. Then you can access that object in the last `.then()`, so replace `console.log(json)` with code that will find the correct question inside the questions array and return the options property from that question object. If you're creating a TODO app, there's hundreds of examples on google: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+todo+app+tutorial

Comment: I already saw this example but I just I had to use JS and JSON file. Thank you for your explanation I will try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to get the JSON file.

```
fetch("../yourFile.JSON").then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
   //do something with your JSON
});
```

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1') .then(res => res.json()).then(json => {
    console.log(json);
});
```

Newer browsers support the `responseType` property of the XMLHttpRequest Object and you can set it to 'json' and then get the JSON response with response property of the XMLHttpRequest.

<sub>Note: `responseType='json'` is not supported by IE11</sub>

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest;
req.responseType = 'json';
req.open('GET', "../yourFile.JSON", true);
req.onload  = function() {
   var json = req.response;
   // do something with your JSON
};
req.send(null);
```

```js
var req = new XMLHttpRequest;
req.responseType = 'json';
req.open('GET', "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", true);
req.onload  = function() {
   var json = req.response;
   console.log(json);
   // do something with your JSON
};
req.send(null);
```

To support older browsers, you can use XMLHttpRequest and `JSON.parse` to convert the responseText to JSON.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest;
req.overrideMimeType("application/json");
req.open('GET', "../yourFile.JSON", true);
req.onload  = function() {
   var json = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
   //do something with your JSON
};
req.send(null);
```

```js
var req = new XMLHttpRequest;
req.overrideMimeType("application/json");
req.open('GET', "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", true);
req.onload  = function() {
   var json = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
   console.log(json);
   //do something with your JSON
};
req.send(null);
```

Comment: So I get the JSON file, and I can use the properties contain in the JSON now in the JS file?

Comment: @shirleytb You can use the JSON in the `.then` callback. `fetch("../yourFile.JSON").then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
   //you can use your JSON here
});`

Comment: think you for you help

Comment: @shirleytb No problem.

Comment: I have an other question, I want to use options in order to do a count down after have you got an idea how can I code that in JS I am totally blocked please?

Comment: @shirleytb Ask a new question.

Comment: Your `fetch` example is missing an important step. It's not just you, so many people miss it out I [wrote it up](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) on my anemic little blog. You need to check `response.ok`.